# How to disable beamer's dimming of covered text

Tags: beamer, lists, pause

In Beamer, when you use `\pause` `\uncover`, or `<+->` with itemize, the text that is covered is dimmed. But that could be distracting since people can still read ahead. Is there a way to disable this dimming?

On a similar note, it seems the amount of dimming depends on the level of nesting in a list, which can sometimes be even more frustrating since the next bullet separated by several sub-bullets becomes so much more prominent in the middle of the page. Can this be changed too?

I tried `\only`, but then the text jingles around since the layout thinks the text isn't there. I also tried different themes, but it doesn't seem to change the amount of dimming (of course, I could just be selecting bad themes).

Comment: Don't post the same question on different pages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428080/how-to-disable-beamers-dimming-of-covered-text

Comment: Have a look at [section 17.6 of the `beamer` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsection.17.6): `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` should be what you're after (by the way, this is the default setting).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is covered in Section 17.6 on page 191 of the [`beamer`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) manual.

```
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
```

hides the content completely. Note that, the content which is already presented and become transparent and the content that is still about to be presented can be distinguished with the options of this command.

Comment: can this be controlled locally? Say, I'm happy with the transparency in general, except for one isolated slide. [if it's a complicated question, I'll ask separately]

Comment: @PatrickT Yes you can use `\setbeamercovered{...}` between frames. I don't remember the options by heart but it is in the manual

Comment: @PatrickT You can `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` before that frame and `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` (or other options you prefer) after that frame. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369584/9789) also suggests another alternative.