# Transparency in itemizing

Tags: beamer, itemize

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} 
\begin{itemize} 
\item<1-> a 
\item<2-> b 
\item<3-> c 
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

How to make e.g. a and c to be transparent and b visible? Than e.g. a and b to be transparent and c visible?
I want to use it as a content, that will be shown before beginning of each section to remind which section will be discussed...

Comment: thank you, but not really... Just only very simple as it is on my first example: for "one click" I want to have a slide on that will be the itemization with a and c transparent and b visible, nothing else , "next click" I want to get on another slide.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45626/how-to-disable-beamers-dimming-of-covered-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\only<1>{\item a}
\only<2>{\item b}
\only<3>{\item c}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should add some screen shot ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer As you say. `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\tableofcontents[currentsection]` to show a TOC for the current section, all other sections and subsections greyed out. See my MWE below. Additionally I added the options `only`and `uncover` for the overlay specifications. You can play with them.

I hope this is what you want.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
\begin{document}
    \section{Table of Contents}
    \begin{frame} 
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
    \section{Test-Section}
    \begin{frame} 
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item<1-> a 
            \item<2-> b 
            \item<3-> c 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \begin{frame} 
        \begin{itemize} 
            \only<1>{\item a} 
            \only<2>{\item b}
            \only<3>{\item c}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame} 
        \begin{itemize} 
            \uncover<1>{\item a} 
            \only<3>{\item b}
            \uncover<2-3>{\item c}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame} 
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot of `\tableofcontents[currentsection]`[image: TOC-currentsection]

---

Screenshot of `\uncover` and `\only`

[image: uncover-only]