# How do I set beamer covered as transparent locally?

Tags: beamer, transparent

I knew setting beamer covered as transparent globally using `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`.

How do I make it work only on some slides, but not all slides? Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\setbeamercovered{transparent} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Set beamer covered as transparent}
\begin{block}{block 1}
  block 1
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 3}
  block 3
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Not to set beamer covered as transparent}
\begin{block}{block 1}
  block 1
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 3}
  block 3
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some possibilities. You could either set it within a group for the frames you want it to affect or you could just use a second `\setbeamercovered{}` and change it to whatever behaviour you want for your other slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Set beamer covered as transparent}
\begin{block}{block 1}
  block 1
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 3}
  block 3
\end{block}
\end{frame}
}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Not to set beamer covered as transparent}
\begin{block}{block 1}
  block 1
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 3}
  block 3
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Set beamer covered as transparent}
\begin{block}{block 1}
  block 1
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 3}
  block 3
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\setbeamercovered{} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Not to set beamer covered as transparent}
\begin{block}{block 1}
  block 1
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 2}
  block 2
\end{block}\pause
\begin{block}{block 3}
  block 3
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( 

I tried both ways..

Comment: @ShihabKhan Please ask a new question including a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just paste

```
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
```

inside of whatever frames you want this to apply, and not in the others. Like this;

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
### Content
\end{frame}
```