# Faded text after a pause on beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

I want to create a frame which contains a list whereby after each pause the previous list items fade and a new list item is revealed (not faded), after a final pause I want all the items to become unfaded. I wanted to use \onslide but it doesnt seem to work. Something like this :

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\onslide<1>{\item one item} 
\pause
\onslide<2>{\item two item}
\pause
\onslide<3>{\item three item}
\end{itemize}

\pause

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following default action for the `itemize` environment (replace `5` with the overlay number on which all items should be uncovered):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\pause

\begin{itemize}[<+,5>]
\item one item 
\item two item
\item three item
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what does the <+,5> stand for exactly?

Comment: The `+` means that each item will be uncovered on the next overlay and the additional `5` makes them all uncovered on the 5th overlay.

Comment: May I ask what do I change the 5 to make the items all unfaded from overlays greater and equal to 5 ?

Comment: @σκουλήκι `5-` goes from 5 until the end of the frame

Comment: this has seemed to stop my \pause from working later on in the document, is that possible?

Comment: for some reason this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369573/how-do-i-set-beamer-covered-as-transparent-locally doenst work for me.

Comment: Without seeing a reproducible example, hard to say...

Comment: Both approaches from the linked answer still work for me.